# Getting input value of a radio button in a group without loop

Tags: javascript, html, domdocument

I need to obtain which radio button is checked using plain javascript ( No JQuery ) without looping through each input elements and checking for 'checked' attribute for each.

PS : Jquery solution would also be appreciated :)

Given HTML :

```
      <tr id = "reportLayout">
         <th align="left" style="padding-right: 10px">Layout</th>
            <td>
             <input type="radio" name="layout" value="portrait">Portrait</input>                                                            
             <input type="radio" name="layout" value="landscape">Landscape</input>
            </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: You're missing a `"` after the first `layout`, by the way.

Comment: your html is wrong.... `<input type="radio" name="layout"   value="portrait">Portrait</input>`

Comment: Yeah ! Had issues in pasting my HTML code here ! Hope you understood what I meant :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"PS : Jquery solution would also be appreciated :)"*

OK, use the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
var checkedRB = $('input[type="radio"][name="layout"]:checked');
```

Where the value of the checked radio would be:

```
checkedRB.val();
```

To do it without jQuery the "standard" way to do it is with a loop, but you could also do this if you don't care about IE < 9:

```
var checkedRB = document.querySelectorAll(
                     'input[type="radio"][name="layout"]:checked');
if (checkedRB.length === 0) {
    // none checked
} else {
    alert(checkedRB[0].value);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xHAwX/1/

Comment: You're welcome. The other way to do it if there are only two radios would be to check the first one by default and give it `id="portrait"` because then you could just say `if (document.getElementById("portrait").checked) { /*portrait*/ } else { /*landscape*/ }`

Answer (score 1):

to get the currently checked radio button's

```
$("input[@name=radioname]:checked")
```

Comment: Thanks ! But do You have anything in mind without using JQuery since I am aware of this :)

Comment: in javascript you need to loop thru the radio button's to find which one is checked or which one is not

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are only using radio boxes in reportLayout:

```
$('#reportLayout').find(':checked')
```

will do it;

Answer (score 0):

```
var check = $('input[name:layout]:checked').val();
alert(check);
```

This will give you the value of currently checked radio button.

You can also check that if any radio button is checked or not by

```
var check = $("input[name:layout]:checked").length;
alert(check);
```